# JSDoc an Object, all properties regardless of name get same type

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I want to add JSDocs to my function. I can't figure out how to define an Object whose keys are not important (every key will point to the same type of object). Any way of achieving that ?

```js
/**
 * @typedef EmojiGroupContent
 * @type {Object}
 * @prop {string[]} emojis All Emojis belonging to the group
 * @prop {function} onAdd Runs when the group is unlocked
 *                        (no other emoji in the group is active),
 *                        and the user reacts with an emoji from this group.
 * @prop {function} onDel Runs when the user removes a reaction belonging to this group.
 */
/**
 * @param {object} pool INSTANCE OF POOL
 * @param {Object} groups
 * @param {EmojiGroupContent} groups.anyNameHere <= Can I force all the properties to be of
 *                                               the type EmojiGroupContent, would it also
 *                                               be possible to have the keys to have a JsDoc
 *                                               comment.
 */
const registerEmojiInteraction = (pool, groups) => {
  ...
};

registerEmojiInteraction(POOL, {
  race: {
    emojies : ["", ...],
    onAdd : ()=>{},
    onDel : ()=>{},
  },
  vsrace: {
    ...
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want

```js
/**
 * @param {Object.<string, EmojiGroupContent>} groups
 */
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ecRmlrQ.png It doesn't show the contents of `EmojiGroupContent`, just that it is the type, but the autocomplete works. Is that normal ?

Comment: I guess it's okay. That what i would expect to see for such case